# How to get initial X, Y values (of first touch ACTION_DOWN) in OnTouchListener

Tags: java, android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I need initial *x* and *y* values (the point that moving begun with first touch `ACTION_DOWN`) in order to calculate `deltaX` and `deltaY` as follows;

```
private float mInitialTouchX = Float.NaN;          // # First touch temp var defined globally
...
someView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {         
    @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        switch (event.getAction()) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                MoveViewHorizontally(v, event.getX(), mInitialTouchX);                      
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mInitialTouchX = event.getX();    // # Set initial touch point
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                     
                mInitialTouchX = Float.NaN;       // # Reset initial touch point
                break;
            default: break;
        }
        return false;
    }           
});

private void MoveViewHorizontally(View v, float x, float initialTouchX)
{
    int deltaX = (int)(x - initialTouchX);      

    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();     

    layoutParams.leftMargin += deltaX;
    v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Is there a way that i can get *initial touch values* from `event` or somehow - somewhere else, avoiding usage of global variable `mInitialTouchX` ?

Comment: There isn't. MotionEvents are more or less a direct interface to /dev/input* events. It is just a series of events which have no relation to each other.

Comment: What's wrong with using private variables?

Comment: Off record: Declare them as volatile. (:

Comment: @RGraham Nothing with it's *access modifier*. I'm just trying to move/drag/slide some view inside a row of `ListView` and i'm not very comfortable with the global variable at the top which is entirely independent of rows without association

Comment: @3yanlis1bos why `volatile` in a single threaded environment? All of these event callbacks are running in *UI Thread* as far as i know

Comment: @Zefnus niice :D That's what i'm talking bout. (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there is no better way.  You're doing it the right way.  In fact, if you take a look at the code for [`GestureDetector`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java), you will see that they are doing it more or less the same way.

Comment: @SaroTaşciyan I'm using your code snippet thanks for this. One Issue I'm facing is when I swipe on view and stop swipping but don't take my finger away from view it starts rotating. Instead it should stop.